# Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1

I tried to upgrade with Brew

```
$ brew upgrade stripe/stripe-cli/stripe
```

I got:

```
Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
    arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.
```

AS suggested, I tried

```
$ arch -arm64 brew install
```

But got:

```
Error: Invalid usage: This command requires at least 1 formula or cask argument.
```

I tried installing Rosetta 2 according to this [tutorial](https://nhancv.medium.com/macbook-pro-m1-homebrew-install-error-7170e4816894)

```
$ /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

But I got:

```
Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported.
```

Comment: Consider add `alias brew='arch -arm64 brew'` to your `zshrc/bashrc` file.

Answer (score 28):

Seems homebrew has to be used like this from now on:

```
arch -arm64 brew upgrade
```

Comment: This is new?  Is there a link to docs for this change?

Answer (score 7):

I added the original argument to `arch -arm64 brew upgrade` and it worked

```
$ arch -arm64 brew upgrade stripe/stripe-cli/stripe
```

Comment: yeah, that's what the `...` meant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all other answers seemed like a workaround for me, I would recommend to do this

```
cd /opt
sudo mkdir homebrew
sudo chown $(whoami):admin homebrew
curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

Then just reload terminal and your `brew install xxx` should work just fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you recommend this?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me in tmux since `uname -a` was giving `x86_64`, it should return `arm64` on m1 macs.

I added this to my tmux.conf to make it always start in arm mode.

```
set -g default-command "arch -arch arm64 /bin/zsh"
```

Found this here: [Running tmux on an M1 Mac in arm64 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431722/running-tmux-on-an-m1-mac-in-arm64-mode)